# Conditional show/hide fields based on show/hide links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What I try to do is very simple.

I have some fields in a form that are optional to fill. To make the form look cleaner, I'd like to show simple links as *Add field* and display the optional fields below via js unobstructedly.

If the field is present, it will be saved into the database. The field would also have a delete link. When this delete link is clicked, the field will be removed and also its value from the database when saved.

Seems pretty simple, yet I haven't found a simple approach to this. The whole solution involves many aspects such as passing hidden data to the controller to see if the record was hidden in order to delete its data from the database.

I would prefer a gem already optimized for this purpose but I couldn't found any. What I found is intended for associated records but this is not the case. These are not associations, just optional attributes from the same model.

[nested_form_fields](https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields) gem its also not suitable since it needs a checkbox or radio button to be triggered and not *Add field/Remove field* links which I believe look cleaner.

Is there such thing as a gem to accomplish this simple thing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to send hidden data etc. Why don't you just load all the form fields but `display:none`. When a user clicks the 'show' button you display the field. If the click the hide button, just set the field to null and hide it.

When your form reaches the controller it will save the null value to the db for the hidden fields (same as if you deleted the value).

Comment: That make sense. Still wondering if there's a gem for doing exactly this and avoiding writing the js code.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. simple_forms + jquery should take long at all